# Remove whitespaces when storing to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, trim

Test code:

```
string files = "C:\Hello; C:\Hi; D:\Goodmorning; D:\Goodafternoon; E:\Goodevening";
string[] paths = files.Split(';');

foreach (string s in paths)
{
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

How do I remove the whitespaces before storing it into the array?

Comment: Is it better to use List<string>?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `String.Trim` method, like this:

```
foreach (string s in paths)
{
    MessageBox.Show(s.Trim());
}
```

Alternatively, you can eliminate spaces before they enter `paths`, like this:

```
files.Split(new[]{';', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 8):

.NET 2.0

```
string[] paths = Array.ConvertAll(files.Split(';'), a => a.Trim());
```

.NET 3.5

```
string[] paths = files.Split(';').Select(a => a.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I solved it..

My code:

```
string files = "C:\Hello; C:\Hi; D:\Goodmorning; D:\Goodafternoon; E:\Goodevening";
string[] paths = files.Trim().Split(';');
List<string> cleanPath = new List<string>();

 int x = 0;
 foreach (string s in paths)
 {
     cleanPath.Add(s.Trim());
 }

 foreach(string viewList in cleanPath)
 {
      x++;
      MessageBox.Show(x + ".)" +viewList);//I put x.) just to know whether it still has whitespace characters.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> `string[] paths = Regex.Split(files, @";\W+");`

Of course, you have some additional flexibility in the RegEx too.

Answer (score -3):

You could use this PHP function:
$var = str_replace(" ", "", $var);

Comment: Trim is more suitable in this case, there may be spaces in the middle of the entry.